# Looking for a suggestion for building an APN Server that stores data (token) in SQL

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, apns-php, apn

I originally used http://www.easyapns.com/ as a guide for building my backend and sending push notifications. However I quickly realized that this no longer works, and I'd love to find another solution that works similar.

Essentially I need to store the device and tokens on my backend, and send out push notifications to certain devices in the DB.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [Azure Notification Hubs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/JJ927170.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's your only requirement, there are many services to do this without creating specific backend, like pusher, push robot, google push notification service, etc.... All take care of registration of the token.

If you need to create a specific backend, then it depends of the others requirements, but Web and Github are full of examples on this topic.

Comment: any personal suggestions? easyapns did a thorough guide from start to end. Of creating the backend and deploying.

Comment: My suggestion if you don't need more than just store Tokens and seend a few push message to a group is to use http://pushbots.com/ ...